# Consumer/Producer AWS SQS akka scala with synchrone consumer

Tags: scala, akka, amazon-sqs, producer-consumer, akka-camel

My application have a producer and a consumer. My producer produces messages irregularly. Sometime my queue will be empty, sometime I will have a few messages. 
I would like to have my consumer listen to the queue and when a message is in it, take it and process this message. The process could take hours and I don't want my consumer to take another message of the queue if he doesn't have finished to process the current message.

I think AKKA and AWS SQS can meet my needs. By reading documentations and examples, it seems that akka-camel can simplified my work.

I found this [example](https://github.com/fzakaria/Akka-Camel-SQS) on github.

I am more interested in the configuration of the consumer (the Thread.sleep is just to simulate my processing) :

```
class MySqsConsumer extends Consumer {

  //The SQS URI is an in-only message exchange (autoAck=true)
  override def endpointUri = "aws-sqs://sqs-akka-camel?  amazonSQSClient=#client"

  override def receive = {
    case msg: CamelMessage => {
      println("Start received %s" format msg.bodyAs[String])
      Thread.sleep(4000)
      println("Stop received %s" format msg.bodyAs[String])

    }

  }
 }
```

StackTrace :

```
...
14:38:53.335 [Camel (sqs-akka-camel) thread #0 - aws-sqs://sqs-akka-camel] DEBUG o.a.camel.processor.SendProcessor - >>>> Endpoint[akka://sqs-akka-camel/user/consumer?autoAck=true&replyTimeout=60000+milliseconds] Exchange[Message: Hello World1!]
14:38:54.051 [Camel (sqs-akka-camel) thread #0 - aws-sqs://sqs-akka-camel] DEBUG o.a.camel.processor.SendProcessor - >>>> Endpoint[akka://sqs-akka-camel/user/consumer?autoAck=true&replyTimeout=60000+milliseconds] Exchange[Message: Hello World2!]
14:38:54.753 [Camel (sqs-akka-camel) thread #0 - aws-sqs://sqs-akka-camel] DEBUG o.a.camel.processor.SendProcessor - >>>> Endpoint[akka://sqs-akka-camel/user/consumer?autoAck=true&replyTimeout=60000+milliseconds] Exchange[Message: Hello World3!]
Start received Hello World1!
Stop received Hello World1!
Start received Hello World2!
Stop received Hello World2!
Start received Hello World3!
...
```

My problem here is that akka-camel reads the messages from the queue before the receive method is done.

**How can I make my consumer wait the end of the process, before taking a new message? If I am using the wrong tools/libraries, could you direct me towards new tools?**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are using akka streams, but if you are, send your source to a Sink.queue

```
val graph=yourSource.to(Sink.queue)
```

When materialized (`graph.run`) it will return a SinkQueue, you can pull manually items from it. It will use backpressure mechanism, so you don't have to worry about what will happen if you don't pull items.

Note: I ignored generics on purpose! but don't forget them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do it. Camel consumes message from the queue all the time.

You can set `override def autoAck = false` - it will not send another message to `receive()`, until you acknowledged the current one. But the "hidden" camel actor will still be consuming.

Maybe you can provide a customized `amazonSQSClient` and somehow control it.